# How to programmatically set the value of a timer?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I tried reading the documentation for the WinForms `Timer` class but I didn't understand it well enough. I want to have a timer that counts down from 60 to 0 seconds and a button that manually adds 10 seconds to the timer whenever pressed. My question is: "what do I need to do to programmatically set the 'value' of a timer"?

I realize this is a simple question, but the answer to it has eluded me. I would be really thankful if I could get some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Winforms, WebForms, WPF?

Comment: Winforms. Sorry, edited.

Answer (score 1):

You need another variable to hold the time. The timer will be responsible for the ticking and it will update the time in your variable. So like this:

```
int timeLeft = 60;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timeLeft > 0)
    {
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    textBox1.Text = timeLeft.ToString();
}

private void StartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void AddTimeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeLeft = timeLeft + 10; 
}
```

`timer1` would be the timer, `textBox1` for showing the time left, and the buttons should be self-explanatory.

Comment: You shouldn't actually have to do any locking for this. Winform timers tick on the UI thread so you won't have any multithreading issues.  If you were using Threading.Timer then locking would be an issue.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Okay, thanks for telling me. Good to learn a new thing every day :)

Answer (score 0):

The timer measures time in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second).  If you want something to update every second set the .Interval to 1000. You will need a variable initially set to 60.  In the timer's Tick event you will want to decrement that counter by one and update your UI.  When you want to start counting down enable the timer with .Enabled = True.  When the counter hits 0 disable the timer.

If you let us know what language you are writing this in (C#, VB, etc) someone can probably give you some actual code.